# Message was sent to a deallocated object (ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

In my app I've a `UITableView` in which I have custom `UITableViewCell`s and those cells contain `UIWebView` in which I am displaying `YouTube` video using `<iframe>`. When I click on a video and instantly scroll the table before a full screen player opens, the app crashes. I tried `Instruments` to find the problem and came to know that `An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'AAHomeNewsListCell' object (zombie) at address: 0x118e09800.`

[image]  ￼

I'm using ARC and I can't find a way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a message to an object that is no longer alive. The best way to debug that problem would probably be to set a break point as close as you can to where the situation happens, and step through the code. A good place to start would be close to where you use an AAHomeNewsListCell-object, or close to where you trigger the full screen player.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say that the web view is messaging its delegate but the delegate has already been deallocated. `UIWebViewDelegate` comes with this handy warning:

> Important: Before releasing an instance of UIWebView for which you have set a delegate, you must first set the UIWebView delegate property to nil before disposing of the UIWebView instance. This can be done, for example, in the dealloc method where you dispose of the UIWebView.

Looking at your zombie message, what is it that would be still trying to message the cell? Is your cell acting as the web view's delegate?

**Edit** Looking at what message is being sent, it gets `_setFirstResponder:`. It could be a text entry form in the web view that's trying to get first responder to enter text.

Comment: No, my cell is not acting as webview's delegate, it's just that the youtube video still load from the cell that is no more visible (deallocated by tableview?).

Comment: Try sending `endEditing:` to the cell in its `dealloc`, as well as properly releasing the web view delegate.